# Swift 3: How to get text from individual textfields that are in different collectionView cells?

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple `UICollectionView` that has 3 cells. The cell has it's own class and all 3 cells use this class. The cell class just has a `UITextField` that is the cells size. I want to know how to be able to get hold of whatever is entered in each of the 3 cells `UITextFields` and pass it into my SecondController. How do I achieve this? Thank you guys. Code is below:

```
import UIKit

class FirstCell: BaseCell {

    var secondController: SecondController?

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let tv = UITextField()
        tv.textColor = .white
        return tv
    }()

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()
        backgroundColor = .lightGray

        addSubview(textField)

        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    }
}

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class SecondController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        self.collectionView?.register(FirstCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Print", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handlePrint))
    }

    func handlePrint() {
        // print here...
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? FirstCell

        cell?.secondController = self

        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell?.textField.placeholder = "First Textfield"
        }

        if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell?.textField.placeholder = "Second Textfield"
        }

        if indexPath.item == 2 {
            cell?.textField.placeholder = "ThirdTextfield"
        }

        return cell!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create protocol

```
protocol MyCellTextFieldDelegate {
    func didChangeTextTo(text: String)
}
```

then

```
extension SecondController: MyCellTextFieldDelegate {
    func didChangeTextTo(text: String) {
        //doStuff
    }
}
```

inside your cell change

```
var secondController: SecondController?
```

to

```
weak var delegate: MyCellTextFieldDelegate?
```

and change your method to be like

```
override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()
    backgroundColor = .lightGray
    addSubview(textField)
    textField.delegate = self //this line
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged) //and this line
    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
}
```

and your cell class

```
class FirstCell: BaseCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //other code

    private func textFieldDidChange() {
        self.delegate?.didChangeTextTo(text: (self.textField.text ?? ""))
    }
}
```

and inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell?.delegate = self
```

Edit: if you would like to get `UICollectionViewCell` that calls this, you should add

```
var tag: Int = 0
```

inside your cell and inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell?.tag = indexPath.row
```

and then change your `MyCellTextFieldDelegate` func to pass not only `text` but `tag` as well.